# Counter Size in AES Driver in CTR mode in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, openssl, cryptography, aes, embedded-linux

I have seen multiple open source drivers for AES(CTR) mode for different Crypto Hardware Engines, I was not really sure on counter size,nonce etc.
Please can any one provide some info on the following

## Q1:

How does AES driver identifies the counter size during the CTR mode of operation?

looks like AES in CTR mode supports "countersize" of multiple lengths as below:

> > 1: First is a counter which is made up of a nonce and counter. The nonce is random, and the remaining bytes are counter bytes (which are incremented).
> >      For example, a 16 byte block cipher might use the high 8 bytes as a nonce, and the low 8 bytes as a counter.
> >
> > 2: Second is a counter block, where all bytes are counter bytes and can be incremented as carries are generated.
> >      For example, in a 16 byte block cipher, all 16 bytes are counter bytes

## Q2:

Does Linux Kernel Crypto subsystem increments the counter value for every block of input or is it needs tp be taken care by Kernel Driver for the respective Crypto H/W ?

## Q3:

counters and nonces are something which will be extracted from the IV i.e., IV = nonce + counter .Note if "l" is length of IV then first "l/2" is length of nonce and next "l/2" is length of counter.Please let me know if my understanding regarding IV,counter and nonce is correct or not?

Any information regarding the above is really appreciable.

BR,
& Sanumala

Comment: The 3rd question is not a question. The second question is quite confusing. The first question can be answered by "this is how the developer chose to implement this. It is not completely standardized."

Comment: Hi Artjom ,  " It is not completely standardized" ,then how the crypto drivers present in the linux kernel are handling this? ,if at all I want to find the the counter size in my linux kernel driver there should be a way to find ,right? . Please correct me if I am wrong. Meanwhile , I have edited Q2 and Q3 also.

Comment: I don't know the linux kernel driver does this, but it seems you answered your own question with the quote that you provided under Q1.

Comment: Hi Artjom , If you look closely Q1 , in first case counter size is "8" (nonce is remaining 8) ,but in second case counter size is 16 ,

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

> How does AES driver identifies the counter size during the CTR mode of operation?

It most likely doesn't. As long as it sees the IV as one big 128 bit counter then there isn't a problem. If the counter would be 64 bit and initialized on all zeros then you would only have a problem after 2^64 = 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 (16 byte) blocks of data; that's not likely to happen.

> Does Linux Kernel Crypto subsystem increments the counter value for every block of input or is it needs tp be taken care by Kernel Driver for the respective Crypto H/W ?

It needs to be taken care by the kernel driver. I only see an IV as input in the API. This is commonly the case for crypto API's. You cannot get any performance if you have to update the counter for each 16 bytes you want to encrypt.

> counters and nonces are something which will be extracted from the IV i.e., IV = nonce + counter .Note if "l" is length of IV then first "l/2" is length of nonce and next "l/2" is length of counter.Please let me know if my understanding regarding IV,counter and nonce is correct or not?

Yes, you understand correctly. You would only have a problem if the protocol uses a separate nonce and counter and *both* are generated randomly. In that case you may have a problem with the carry from the counter to the nonce field.

Note that it may be a good idea to limit the data size to, say ~68 GB and use the top 12 bytes as a random nonce to avoid being bitten by the birthday problem.

Comment: Hi Maarten , Thanks for the information shared.  "If the counter would be 64 bit" ,in my kernel driver how will I find the whether counter size is of 64 bit or 128 bit?